# Classification algorithm robust to variance?

Tags: correlation, classification, algorithms

tldr version: What's an algorithm I can use to classify different series with very different standard deviations across a single variable?

I'm working with data that follows changes of stock prices through non-sequential, uncorrelated, instances of time.  I would like to group stocks together that tend to change price at the same time.

My first thought was K-nearest neighbors, but I would need it to be radial and the different variances make it difficult to set a threshold radius.  Maybe I just need a good way to normalize the data?

Classifying based on a correlation matrix seems like a good idea to me.  Most of the data could be sorted by simply setting a threshold correlation, but then there are some stocks that belong to more than one group and others that don't belong to any groups.

Rather than try to design something from scratch, I'm guessing there's a widely used algorithm that would work well for my purpose.  Any suggestions are welcome.

Edit: In case it wasn't clear, I'm working with a single variable, which is price.